# Unable to clone a git repo

Tags: git, github, ssh, access-denied

I am trying to setup my build server (Windows 2008 machine) to build my project from github enterprise but I am getting `Permission Denined (Public Key)` when I try to clone a repo. I have generated ssh key and added it to github profile.

This is what I have when I try to test ssh connection and clone the repo.

```
D:>ssh -T git@git.company.com
Hi my_user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

D:\>git clone git@git.company.com:myOrg/leaf.git
Cloning into 'leaf'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried this with both git bash and windows command prompt.

Please let me know if there is anything I am missing or if you need any more information.

Comment: You might need to specify your IdentityFile in your ~/.ssh/config.

Comment: Concentrate on one environment, the windows command prompt is not the same environment as the git bash environment.  You say that you added your key to the github profile, but you indicate that you are using github enterprise.  Are you sure that the two services communicate together to know that you have provided your ssh key to one, but not the other?  You need to provide your public key to the place that git.company.com states it needs to be.  I would venture that you need to ask your service provider (at company.com) rather than SO for assistance with this.

Answer (score 1):

Github denies your access which means either SSH keys are not setup or public Key is not associated with the private key in the github.

1. Try to generate the ssh key and add to the .ssh/ as id_rsa.pub in the github.
2. Use https instead of ssh

Comment: OP says that github enterprise is being used, he is attempting to validate against git.company.com when he submitted his public key.  I doubt it is github that is denying the request, as he is requesting against another server.

Comment: if you look at the post github is not denying the access. It did successfully authenticated when I tried it using `ssh -T`. I tried regenerating the keys and adding the keys didn't help. Also I verifyed ssh fingerprint on both local and github and they match.

Answer (score -1):

try on Git Bash:
$ *git config --global -l*

If the response is something as : *http.proxy=http://:0* . Then you have to unset the http proxy server:

$ *git config --global --unset http.proxy*

now try cloning and it should go through